# Chi Square Statistic - Which variable should be defined as the dependent variable?

Tags: self-study, spss, chi-squared-test

I am stuck with this very basic question which I need to answer using SPSS for the problem set pasted in cursive below. Any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

*For the GSS2010, respondents were asked to report which candidate they voted for in the 2004 and 2008 presidential elections (PRES04 and PRES08) and their feelings about the Bible (BIBLE). Does a relationship exist between a respondent’s 2008 vote and her or his feelings about the Bible?*

**Which variable should be defined as the dependent variable?**

Exercise Nr.4 (a) available here: https://edge.sagepub.com/ssdsess2e/student-resources/chapter-9/spss-exercises

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Comment: Some things to get you started  1. For a chi-square it's not necessary to define any variable as the DV; it's a test of assocation. 2. However, there's a fairly obvious choice for DV and IV here. 3. If "feelings about the bible" is ordered, a chi-square will tend to be less powerful against interesting alternatives than an analysis that takes the ordering into account.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for your comment. You suggest 'BIBLE' as IV and 'PRES08' as DV? If possible could you kindly point me to a source that can help me understand your reasoning? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot tell the IV from the DV using statistical methods.

In an experiment, the IV is the one(s) that you manipulate.

In an observational study, like the one in the example, neither is manipulated so, you have to use logic.  In this case, ask yourself: Does it make sense to say that people believe in the Bible because they voted for Obama or Romney?  No. People's belief (or lack of belief) in the Bible precedes their vote - at least in the vast majority of cases. On the other hand, does it make sense to say that people voted for a particular candidate because of their belief? Yes.

Next, think about the proper method of analysis. Read the rest of the question and ask yourself whether chi-square can answer all parts of the question